# Is it possible to override the behaviour of the len function for a custom type?

Tags: go

I've defined a custom type which consists of, among other things, an unexported array. 
What I'm wondering is, is there a way for me to override the implementation of the `len()` function for my custom type without having to export the array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. You can however add a `Len()` method to your type.